# Some questions about convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I'm getting lost in the first couple of sentences of a paper by Cafarelli & Alt. The sections are organized as follows, 1.1 Data, 1.2 The problem, 1.3 the statement and relevant part of proof.

1.1 Data

> $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open connected (may be unbounded) set, and locally $\partial \Omega$ is a Lipschitz graph. $S \subset \partial \Omega$ is measurable and $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(S)>0$. The Dirchlet data on $S$ are given by a non-negative function $u^0 \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ with $\nabla u^0 \in L^2(\Omega)$. The given function $Q$ is non-negative and measurable.

1.2 The problem

> Consider the convex set:
> $$K = \{v \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)/\nabla v \in L^2(\Omega)\text{ and } v = u^0 \text{ on } S\}$$
> Find the absolute minimum of the functional $$J(v) = \int_{\Omega}|\nabla v|^2 + \chi(\{v > 0 \}Q^2)$$
> where $v \in K$.

1.3 Existence Statement and Proof

> If $J(u^0)<\infty$ then there exists an absolute minimum $u \in K$ of the functional $J$.
>
> Since $J$ is non-negative there is a minimal sequence $u_k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\nabla u_k$ are bounded in $L^2(\Omega)$, and since $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(S)$ is positive $u_k - u^0$ are bounded in $L^2(B_R \cap \Omega)$ for large $R$. Therefore there is an $u \in K$, such that for a subsequence:
> $$\nabla u_K \rightarrow \nabla u$$
> weakly in $L^2(\Omega)$ and
> $$u_k \rightarrow u$$
> a.e. in $\Omega$. Moreover there is a function $\gamma \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with $0 \leq \gamma \leq 1$ such that $$\chi(\{u_k > 0\}) \rightarrow \gamma$$ weak star in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

My questions:

1. The authors write "Since $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ is positive $u_k -u^0$ are bounded in $L^2(B_R \cap \Omega)$ for large $R$". I don't follow this. What allows them to go from the Hausdorff measure of the boundary to some estimate locally on the interior? I was thinking like some divergence theorem thing but I can't be sure.
2. The authors write "$u_k \rightarrow u\text{ a.e. in }\Omega$". This confuses me. I know convergence in measure implies a subsequence converging a.e. But he has the $u_k \in L^2_{loc}$ -- so I dont know where this fact is coming from.
3. Where does the final fact come from? -- $$\chi(\{u_k > 0\}) \rightarrow \gamma$$ weak star in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$

Comment: could you give a reference to the paper?

Comment: H. W. Alt & L. A. Caffarelli, Existence and regularity for a minimum problem with
free boundary, J. Reine Angew. Math. 325 (1981), 105–144

Comment: 1) is the Poincare inequality: $u_k - u^0$ is zero on $S$, and $S \subseteq \partial(B_R \cap \Omega)$ for $R$ large enough, so there you have the Poincare inequality for $u_k - u^0$ on $B_R \cap \Omega$. 3) Is the Banach-Alaoglu theorem in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ since the characteristic functions are uniformly bounded in $L^\infty$ norm by $1$.

Comment: and again, 2) is the application of poincare inequality

Comment: Yes; I'd say 2) is a consequence of 1) plus some tedious stuff on how to transfer the subsequences converging pw. a.e. on $B_R \cap \Omega$ to the whole $\Omega$. But maybe there is a direct argument which I am not seeing.

Comment: okay I'm almost there: for 1) Applying the poincare inequality gives: $$\|u_k - u^0\|_{L^1_{loc}} \leq \|Du_k - Du^0\|_{L^1_{loc}}$$
How do I get to $u_k-u^0$ are bounded in $L^2_{loc}$, I checked the relevant embedding theorem but it seems to be going the wrong way (Folland, Real Analysis 6.12)

Comment: you can use the Poincaré inequality with $p=2$ instead of $p=1$! (here this is OK because the sequence of gradients is bounded in $L^2$ and the boundary datum is fixed)